# Can any Texter users answer this question?

Tags: html, text-editor

I have recently started using the excellent [Texter](http://lifehacker.com/software//lifehacker-code-texter-windows-238306.php).  I wanted to set up a shortcut for creating html comments. However that it seems that the exclamation character (!) has special significance in the program, and so does not come out in script mode.

This character is of course required for...`<!-- html comment here -->`

Here is the code I tried to create the shortcut...

```
{HOME}<!-- {END}{BS} -->
```

Just wondering if there is a way of getting around this problem??

Cheers

Comment: I don't know Texter, but in many programming languages to use a special character in its literal form you precede it with a backslash. IMHO `\!` is worth a try

Comment: A good idea Ben. But it didn't work I'm afraid.
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"To send the literal forms of the special characters above, just wrap them in the same curly brackets." So something like `{HOME}<{!}-- {END}{BS} -->`. From [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/software/texter/lifehacker-code-texter-windows-238306.php).